# Obtain absolute URL Path on both Windows and Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows

I am including a file called includes/db.php which in turn requires connection_details.php

The issue I am having is I must read the content of db.php with this following line.

```
$dbSettingsFile = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) )."\connection-details.txt";
$lines = file($dbSettingsFile);//file in to an array
```

But if I am in turn already including the db.php file from a file that is something like.
/subfolder/file.php

with the line

```
require('../includes/db.php');
```

But this will always work on windows but am I right in saying because of the backward slash in the $dbSettingsFile variable it will not work in linux?
I have to be very specific like this because if you removed the realpath and ran file.php it would not pick up the correct path.

Comment: Use the `PHP_EOL` constant (or just a normal slash `/`) if in doubt. Windows will accept both.

Comment: `PHP_EOL`? Do you mean `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use absolute filename, because you can't be sure about base directory where search for relative path will start.

Use

`require( __DIR__ . '/../includes/db.php' );`

to be sure.

Slash character '/' will work as directory separator in both Windows and Linux.
Be careful - in Windows filenames 'db.php' and 'DB.php' are the same file but not in Linux.